# When will the loop stop?

Tags: c, double

so this is a code that increments x value by 1 while the condition is true.Questions is when this loop will stop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    double x=1;
    while(x+1>x)
    {
        x++;
        printf("%f\n",x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it stops when `x` reaches the accuracy limit (somewhere around 2^52 or 2^53 or thereabouts)... ie, when `x+1 == x`

Comment: At the point where `double` can no longer accurately represent all the digits in the integer value.  There are [typically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats) 24 value bits in a `float`, 53 in a `double`; the answer is probably around 2^53 (power of), give or take a couple in the exponent.  It will take a long time to run as shown — if you manage to process 1 loop per nanosecond, it'll still take of the order of millions of seconds to complete — so multiple days of running time.

Comment: What's the source of this question? Why do you ask? Is there a practical reason behind it or are you just posing a brainteaser?

Comment: Floating point numbers must be de-normalised to the same power of 2 before addition and then normalised with the msb of the significand aligned at the top. If when the `1` is denormalised the significand becomes `0` then nothing can be added.

Comment: @JohnKugelman CS class assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will stop when `x` gets so large that the precision of floating point can't hold all the digits. At that point, adding 1 doesn't change the value, so `x + 1 == x` and the loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose double had 2 bits (and the implicit 1st bit) for mantissa and we don't worry about exponent (or signal)

```
1 == [1]00+0
2 == [1]00+1
3 == [1]10+1
4 == [1]00+2
5 == [1]01+2
6 == [1]10+2
7 == [1]11+2
8 == [1]00+3
9 == <cannot represent>
10 == [1]01+3
```

Now suppose arithmetic is done with 3 bits

```
[1]000+3 + [1]000+0 ----- 8 + 1
[1]001+3            ----- 9
```

that last value (9) truncates to `8` when it goes back to 2 bits mantissa.